PowerApp Import Excel in to existing table The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request
I try to upload Excelsheet in to an existing PowerApp table. The Excelfile is localy stored on the laptop.

I try to use the import -> import data from excel functionality in PowerApp. I need to do some manuel mappings to map the excel columns to the target table columns.


I press Save Changes -> Import
After the proces is finish i get the following error

When i look at the error i get the following error:

Type=Microsoft.Dynamics.Integrator.Exceptions.IntegratorClientException,
Msg=Unable to parse import file a694f5f2c7f94f0fb8b5b363fe7068bf.xlsx
Error details PQOnline failure - Type=System.Net.WebException, Msg=The
remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

I don't know what i do wrong and how to solve it. Can you please help me ?
